# Console always writes same numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I don't know whats wrong but i keep get the same outcome in console :

> ```
> 111
> 118
> 101
> 114
> ```
>
> i solved that problem but now my console doesn't show me anything.
>   i updated my code!

this is my exercise:
 Write a program and ask the user to continuously enter a number or type "Quit" to exit. The list of numbers may include duplicates. Display the unique numbers that the user has entered.

this is my code:

```
    while (true)
    {
        var numbers = new List<int>();
        Console.WriteLine("write a number or type quit if you want to exit, if you want to finish write over: ");
        var input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input.ToLower() == "quit")
        {
            break;
        }
        if (input.ToLower() == "over")
        {
            var uniq = new List<int>();
            foreach (var other in numbers)
            {
                Convert.ToInt32(other);
                if (!uniq.Contains(other))
                {
                    uniq.Add(other);
                    Convert.ToInt32(other);
                    Console.WriteLine(other);

                    continue;
                }
                int cifre;
                if (int.TryParse(input, out cifre))
                {
                    numbers.Add(cifre);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, type 'quit', 'over' or a numeric value");
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

thanks for helping.

I figured it out i just had to copy this line:

> var numbers = new List();
>   to the top of while loop  and use practicly everything the same i had at the bignning (because of the loop list wasnt sabving numbers in itself). i will edit my code so you can se rescued exercise.

Hope it helps someone

```
    var numbers = new List<int>();


 while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("enter a number or quit or over");
            var input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "quit")
            {
                break;
            }

            if (input == "over")
            {
                var uniq = new List<int>();

                foreach (var value in numbers)
                {

                    if (!uniq.Contains(value)) {
                        uniq.Add(value);
                    }
                }
                foreach (var numbr in uniq) {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbr);

                }
            }
            else { 
                // inpout dodas v numbers
                var conv = Convert.ToInt32(input);
                numbers.Add(conv);
            }
        }


            }
}
```

thanks for helping

Comment: Try to click build and then clean solution

Comment: what do you expect the line `Convert.ToInt32(other);` to do?

Comment: tried but it's still the same

Comment: i expect it to convert it from type string to int? i am a beginner so i could be wrong

Comment: You are converting each char on the lin to a different number, per example, if you enter "95" you would add the char 9 and the char 5 as integers, what translates to 57 and 53.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are some issues with the logic of the code. Here is the pseudo code I came up with to help you out:

```
While (true) 
    if (quit) 
       //end program
    if (over) 
       //print out the list of integers
    else 
       if (input is not a number)
           continue
       if (number is not in list)
           //add to list
       else 
           //do nothing
```

This should help you rewrite the program.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var numbers = new List<int>();
        
        Console.WriteLine("Enter numbers or Quit");
        while (true)
        {
            var value = Console.ReadLine();
            if (value == "Quit")
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!numbers.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(value)))
                numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(value));
            }
        }

        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
```

Comment: `HashSet` would be better since you could avoid the need for the `Contains` call.

Answer (score 0):

Before you check whether the user has typed "over", you have already converted the characters in the input data and added them to the list. In other words, you're adding the ASCII character values of `'o'`, `'v'`, `'e'`, `'r'` to the numeric list.

Move the "over" check and ensure they do not get added to the list:

```
while (true)
{
    ...input stuff
    if (input.ToLower() == "quit")
    {
        break;
    }

    if (input.ToLower() == "over")
    {
        ...make unique and report
        continue;
    }

    foreach (var number in input)
    {
        var cifre = Convert.ToInt32(number);
        numbers.Add(cifre);
    }
}
```

This will solve your issue of having these same numbers in the list. You might also want to replace your `foreach` with:

```
int cifre;
if (int.TryParse(input, out cifre))
{
    numbers.Add(cifre);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input, type 'quit', 'over' or a numeric value");
}
```

Assuming you want to input a single numeric value each time.

Comment: can you show me please i dont understand i just started with c#

Comment: now i dont get displayed those numbers but now i don't get any outcome i will edit my post so you will se the code i have now

Comment: The code to add numbers is now located inside the `if (input.ToLower() == "over")` block - it should be placed outside. And the `continue` operation should come after the `foreach` block.